# REST Webservice client implementation

Tags: restful-url

I am learning Restful web service and have one doubt.  I tried to search but did not get the answer.

In SOAP web service there is WSDL which contains the details about methods and its parameters which helps to client to write client code.

I wanted to know how Restful client get the information about methods name and its parameter?

Comment: Are you asking how RESTful architecture works in general, or is there a specific API you're asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Restful client cannot discover like SOAP service does. You need API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Restful webservices generally communicates with json datas. So there is no definition like wsdl in soap webservices and xml data. In this way restful ws are much lightweight. You should well document your api and must version your api.

There is some tools for document easily resful webservices:

http://www.jsondoc.org

http://www.miredot.com/

http://apiblueprint.org/

I hope this information and tool helps you.